# Why did Karna flee from battle with Chitrasena (Gandharvas)?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, karna

First of all, I am a great admirer of Karna and can prove that he is the only person in Mahabharata epic to follow dharma in his entire life but the only question I have is why did he ran from the battle with Chitrasena abandoning Duryodhana?

His first dharma was protecting Duryodhana. Why did he flee saving his own life (which was not necessary as he had Kavacha-Kundala with him). Karna fans argue that he was drunk at that time and was not in a position to use his full capabilities. But I'm not convinced. If a drunk person commits a crime he is still a criminal. Moreover, it is not mentioned (in Sacred-Texts.com, from where I read it) that he was drunk.

Having Kavacha-Kundala on him, Karna was invincible still he fled from the battle abandoning the friend whom he promised to protect him against any cause, if required with his life, why he fled away? Did he want to protect his prestige of not becoming captive to any power or remain undefeated throughout his life? Even if it is so, running from a battle would also be considered a defeat. What is the truth? Did he run or not? If he did, why did he do that? Is [Sacred-Texts.com](http://Sacred-Texts.com) legitimate? For I know Karna would never flee for his life abandoning his best friend Duryodhana.

> All the Gandharvas then, desirous of slaying Karna, rushed together by
> hundreds and thousands towards Karna. And those mighty warriors,
> desirous of slaying the Suta's son, surrounded him on all sides, with
> swords and battle-axes and spears. And some cut down the yoke of his
> car, and some his flagstaff, and some the shaft of his car, and some
> his horses, and some his charioteer. And some cut down his umbrella
> and some the wooden fender round his car and some the joints of his
> car. It was thus that many thousands of Gandharvas, together attacking
> his car, broke it into minute fragments. And while his car was thus
> attacked, Karna leaped therefrom with sword and shield in hand, and
> mounting on Vikarna's car, urged the steeds for saving himself.
>
> Source: [sacred-texts.com - The Mahabharata, Vana Parva, Sec. CCXXXIX](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03239.htm)

Comment: Karna ran away from battle field many times and not just during the fight with citrasena. Please read the kurushetra battle field sections from Mahabharata. Karna was defeated by Bhima and Karna had to flee from kurushetra battle and then returned.

Comment: That was due to Sammohana weapon. It was highly prohibited in any war. The weapon was a boon from lord Indra to Arjuna. The boon was if the weapon is used in a war it will hypnotise all the warriors and make the fall asleep. It was imminent to flee from such situation. Bheeshma knew the neutralize the Sammohana weapon bud did not want to used against his beloved Arjuna. Anyway that weapon does not show any archery skill. If Indra gave it to Shakuni he would be greatest warrior in that war. It was rather a tactic used by Indra to protect his son. I would say Arjuna showed cowardice using it.

Comment: You havent read my comment properly.  Please read it again. Also, who said samohana astra was prohibited? Dont write your own commentaries, please. Moreover, i am not even comparing Karna with Arjuna. I am just saying that Karna lost number of times and ran away from battlefield.

Comment: Be happy in Karna syphocancy world. You havent yet said which scripture says sammohana astra is prohibited? Wow, Karna went for recovery when defeated by Bhima, that too in batle of archery. This incident is sufficient to prove that Karna was not a great archer as many sycophants of his advocate.

Comment: I am not advocating Karna. Neither am I concerned he was the best in Archery or not. I don't care who is better - Arjuna or Karna. But I need not to speak a word to prove Karna was better than Bhima in Archery. Everyone knows it. Now can you answer my original question? If not then don't extend the conversation.

Comment: there is one thing many overlook. his guru parashurama after cursing karna said that if he fights for the side with more dharma he will fight with his full skill otherwise he will be able to fight with only threefourth of his full prowess.

Comment: ARJUN too never defeated CHITRASEN,,, CHITRASEN liked ARJUNA ,when arjun came to heaven,just left his captive DURYODHAN on ARJUN request,, no one can ever defeat CHITRASEN

Comment: I agree sammohan astra was not prohibited. The nallika astra was banned in the sastras. It was used by ravan's son indrajit and later by arjun against karna. But once Lord Krishna said to yudhisthir that sometimes the only way remain to protect dharma is to forget it.

Comment: *"can prove that he is the only person in Mahabharata epic to follow dharma in his entire life"* - you must write your own version of Mahabharata then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on Quora and got the answer:

"the Kuru prince, surrounded by thecowherds, began to # sport and wander
cheerfully. And the citizens also and the soldiers by thousands began to sport, as best pleased them, in those woods, like the celestials. And the
herdsmen, well skilled in singing and dancing and instrumental music, and virgins decked in ornaments, began to minister to the pleasures of
Dhritarashtra's son. And the king surrounded by the ladies of the royal household began cheerfully to distribute wealth and food and # drinks_of_various_kinds amongst those that sought to please him, according to their desires (this passage clearly mentions they were drunk )

Duryodhana and others were making merriment there, they were celebrating a party. Duryodhana, surrounded by the Kuru ladies, distributed
wealth, food and various types of drinks among his followers (i.e. Karna, Sakuni, and other Kuru princes).

---

Duryodhana and others were celebrating a party there, so it is obvious that the drinks that they were taking was not water or milk. [Lol... were
Karna and Duryodhana children that they would
drink milk in a party?]

---

Karna, Duryodhana and others were drinking

## wine .

---

"And the king, attended by # all_his_followers , began also to slay hyenas and buffaloes and deer and gayals and bears and boars all around.
And the king, piercing by his shafts those animals by thousands in deep forest, caused the deer to be caught in the more delightful parts of
the woods. Drinking # milk and # enjoying, O Bharata, various other delicious articles and beholding, as he proceeded, many delightful
forests and woods swarming with bees inebriate with floral honey and resounding with the notes of the peacock, the king at last reached the
sacred lake of Dwaitavana."

---

Vana Parva: Ghosha-yatra Parva: Section CCXXXVIII

---

Here it is written that Duryodhana, along with all
his followers (including Karna, Sakuni and
others) were enjoying and drinking milk. This is
complete insanity to think that Kauravas were
celebrating a party by drinking milk. Obviously
they drank some kind of wine (made from milk
and other objects).

---

Conclusion:- Karna and others were drinking wine, obviously they were partially (if not ompletely) drunk during their encounter with the
Gandharvas. This contributed greatly to their defeat in the battle against the Gandharvas.

why Karna fled where Arjuna succeeded against Gandharvas in full detail :

"when the Gandharvas were so commanded by
Chitrasena, they rushed weapons in hand,
towards the Dhritarashtra ranks. And beholding
the Gandharvas impetuously rushing towards
them with upraised weapons, the Kuru warriors
precipitously fled in all directions at the very
sight of Duryodhana."

---

Point-1: The war started here.

---

Point-2: The whole of the Kuru army fled
(including Duryodhana, his 100 brothers and
Sakuni), seeing the Gandharvas rushing towards
them with various weapons.

---

"And beholding the Kuru
soldiers all flying from the field with their backs
to the foe, the heroic Radheya alone fled not."

---

Point: The whole of the Kuru army fled, only
Karna remained on the battlefield.

---

"And seeing the mighty host of the Gandharvas
rushing towards him, Radheya checked them by
a perfect shower of arrows. And the Suta's son,
owing to his extreme lightness of hand, struck
hundreds of Gandharvas with Kshurapras and
arrows and Bhallas and various weapons made
of bones and steel. And that mighty warrior,
causing the heads of numerous Gandharvas to
roll down within a short time, made the ranks of
Chitrasena to yell in anguish."

---

Point-1: Karna alone checked the whole force of
the Gandharvas, and within a short span of time,
he slew hundreds of Gandharvas.

---

Point-2: While fighting with the Gandharvas,
Karna effectively used various types of arrows
and various types of other weapons. And while
using those weapons, he displayed his extreme
lightness of hand.

---

Point-3: Karna alone checked and overwhelmed
the vast Gandharva host.

---

"And although they were slaughtered in great numbers by Karna
endued with great intelligence, yet the
Gandharvas returned to the charge by hundreds
and thousands. And in consequence of the
swarms of Chitrasena's warriors rushing
impetuously to the field the earth itself became
soon covered by the Gandharva host."

---

Point-1: Karna slew a very large number of
Gandharvas.

---

Point-2: In spite of Karna's continuous onslaught,
the Gandharvas continued to rush towards him in
great numbers.

---

Point-3: The Gandharva army was much larger
than the Kuru army. The Gandharvas were so
many in number that the earth seemed to be
filled with the Gandharvas. Karna alone
withstood that vast force.

---

"Then king Duryodhana, and Sakuni, the son of Suvala, and
Dussasana, and Vikarna, and other sons of
Dhritarashtra, seated on cars the clatter of
whose wheels resembled the roars of Garuda,
returned to the charge, following the lead of
Karna, and began to slaughter that host. And
desirous of supporting Karna, these princes
invested the Gandharva army, with a large
number of cars and a strong body of horses.
Then the whole of the Gandharva host began to
fight with the Kauravas. And the encounter that
took place between the contending hosts was
fierce in the extreme and might make one's hair
stand on end."

---

Point-1: When Duryodhana beheld that Karna
alone had checked the vast Gandharva force, he
returned to the battlefield, along with his
brothers and the Kuru army.

---

Point-2: Karna thus got a strong back-up, and
continued to fight.

---

Point-3: A general war commenced between the
Kuru army and the huge Gandharva host.

---

"The Gandharvas, at last, afflicted
with the shafts of the Kuru army, seemed to be
exhausted. And the Kauravas beholding the
Gandharvas so afflicted sent up a loud sound."

---

Point-1: In the general engagement, the Kuru
army led by Karna completely overwhelmed the
Gandharvas.

---

Point-2: At this point of the battle, the
Gandharvas were nearly exhausted, and were on
the verge of defeat.

---

"And seeing the Gandharva host yielding to fear,
the angry Chitrasena sprang from his seat,
resolved to exterminate the Kuru army. And
conversant with various modes of warfare, he
waged on the fight, aided by his weapons of
illusion."

---

Point-1: When Karna, supported by the Kuru
army, had nearly vanquished the Gandharvas,
and the Gandharvas were struck with fear,
Chitrasena (king of the Gandharvas) entered the
battlefield.

---

Point-2: Chitrasena didn't engage in a duel/single
combat with Karna (or any other Kuru warrior).
And, he used neither any ordinary weapon nor
any celestial weapon against the Kuru army. He
directly used an illusion against the Kuru army.
He knew that he wouldn't be able to defeat
Karna in a single combat. He also knew that if
he had used any weapon (be it ordinary or
celestial), Karna would have baffled it with ease.
So he directly used an illusion.

---

Point-3: Chitrasena was a Gandharva.
Gandharvas possessed illusionary powers, and
were well-acquainted with illusions (and
illusionary warfare). But Karna and others in the
Kuru army were humans, who didn't possess
illusionary powers. According to the rules of war,
a warrior/warriors possessed of illusionary
powers should not use illusions against him/
those who doesn't/don't possess illusionary
powers, and if he/they does/do so, that is
considered as 'deceit' and 'violation of rules of
war'. Chitrasena used illusions against Karna and
the Kuru army (who were humans), and thus
violated the rules of war.

---

Note-1: Some people may ask where I have
found that using illusions against those who
didn't possess illusionary powers is a violation of
the rules of war. I would suggest them to read
the narratives of the duel between Abhimanyu
and Alamvusha on the 9th day and the duel
between Karna and Ghatotkacha on the 14th
night. In these duels Alamvusha and Ghatotkacha
(both of whom were Rakshasas, and possessed
of illusionary powers) used illusions against
Abhimanyu and Karna (both of whom were
humans, not possessing illusionary powers)
respectively and both of those Rakshasas were
marked as 'deceitful' for their acts (i.e. using
illusions against human warriors).

---

Note-2: If a warrior possessed of illusionary
powers use illusions against another warrior
possessed of illusionary powers, then that's not a
violation of the rules of war. (In case of
Rakshasa vs Rakshasa, Naga vs Naga,
Gandharva vs Gandharva, Naga vs Rakshasa,
Gandharva vs Rakshasa etc. scenarios)

---

"And the Kaurava warriors were then all
deprived of their senses by the illusion of
Chitrasena. And then, O Bharata, it seemed that
every warrior of the Kuru army was fallen upon
and surrounded by ten Gandharvas. And attacked
with great vigour, the Kuru host was greatly
afflicted and struck with panic. O king, all of
them that liked to live, fled from the field."

---

Point-1: In consequence of Chitrasena's sudden
illusionary attack, all Kuru warriors (including
Karna) were deprived of their senses. Karna and
others were nearly unconscious.

---

Point-2: Beholding the Kuru warriors (including
Karna) almost unconscious owing to the terrible
illusion of Chitrasena, the nearly defeated
Gandharvas attacked them with greater vigour.
This was another violation of the rules of war,
because attacking (or striking) unconscious
warriors was against the rules of war, but the
Gandharvas violated this rule also.

---

Point-3: Being thus attacked, large part of the
Kuru army fled from the battlefield. Only Karna,
Duryodhana, Duryodhana's brothers, Sakuni, and
a smaller portion of the Kuru army remained on
the battlefield.

---

"But while the entire Dhritarashtra host broke and
fled, Karna, that offspring of the Sun, stood there, O king,
immovable as a hill. Indeed, Duryodhana and
Karna and Sakuni, the son of Suvala, all fought
with the Gandharvas, although every one of them
was much wounded and mangled in the
encounter."

---

Point-1: As Karna and few other Kuru warriors
(who remained in the battlefield) were almost
unconscious, the Gandharvas used the
opportunity to mangle and wound them badly.

---

Point-2: Though nearly unconscious and
exceedingly wounded, yet Karna stayed on the
battlefield, and fought to the utmost of his
power.

---

Point-3: Karna lost his back-up force, as all of
them were almost unconscious, practically
useless.

---

At this point, let me clear some doubts that
often arise.

---

Doubt-1: Why did Karna fail to counter
Chitrasena's illusion?

---

Answer: Chitrasena used the illusion suddenly. At
first he wasn't in the battlefield. When Karna had
nearly defeated the Gandharvas, he suddenly
entered the battlefield and just after entering,
used a terrible illusion to make Karna and others
unconscious. Chitrasena did it without any
warning or challenge. He used deceit to defeat
Karna and others. Also people may question why Karna didn't use
any celestial weapon to counter the illusion (as
though he was nearly unconscious, yet he wasn't
completely senseless). The answer is Karna was
already drunk (though not completely, but he
drank wine just before the war, so it is obvious
that he was partially drunk), and when Chitrasena
used illusion, he became almost unconscious,
and in that condition, it wasn't possible to invoke
into existence celestial weapons as in order to
shoot celestial weapons complete concentration
is required (and it is completely foolishness to
expect that a drunk and almost unconscious
warrior could have complete concentration).
So, this is the reason why Karna had failed to
counter Chitrasena's illusion.

---

Doubt-2: Karna possessed his impenetrable
armour and ear-rings during Gandharva War.
Then how was he defeated?

---

Answer: Karna's armour and ear-rings had made
him immortal/unslayable, but it hadn't made him
invincible/undefeatable. Karna's armour and ear-
rings used to protect him from mortal/lethal/
deadly threats only, not from defeat.

---

Doubt-3: How did the Gandharvas manage to
mangle Karna exceedingly as Karna possessed
his impenetrable armour at that time?

---

Answer: Karna was exceedingly mangled, but it
is not mentioned in which parts of the body he
was mangled. So, it can be assumed that the
Gandharvas mangled those parts of Karna's body
which were not covered by his armour (forehead,
neck, hands, thighs etc.).
Karna also used the same technique to mangle
Abhimanyu on the 13th day of the Kurukshetra
War, when the latter was encased in an
impenetrable armour.

---

Doubt-4: Karna failed to counter Chitrasena's
illusion, so was he a poor warrior?

---

Answer: No, not at all. Karna failed to counter
Chitrasena's illusion owing to some specific
factors (Karna's being drunk, his being almost
unconscious, use of deceit by Chitrasena). But
when Karna fought with the same Gandharvas
during his digvijay, he successfully countered
their illusions and defeated them easily. Also
Karna successfully countered hundreds of terrible
illusions created by Rakshasa Ghatotkacha.

---

"All the Gandharvas then, desirous of
slaying Karna, rushed together by hundreds and
thousands towards Karna. And those mighty
warriors, desirous of slaying the Suta's son,
surrounded him on all sides, with swords and
battle-axes and spears. And some cut down the
yoke of his car, and some his flagstaff, and
some the shaft of his car, and some his horses,
and some his charioteer. And some cut down his
umbrella and some the wooden fender round his
car and some the joints of his car. It was thus
that many thousands of Gandharvas, together
attacking his car, broke it into minute
fragments."

---

Point-1: Though Karna was almost unconscious
and exceedingly wounded, yet he continued to
fight with the Gandharvas, slaying many of them.

---

Point-2: Considering Karna as their main threat,
the Gandharvas concentrated their attack on
Karna.

---

Point-3: Many thousands of Gandharvas, armed
with various kinds of weapons, together attacked
on Karna's chariot.

---

Point-4: An exceedingly wounded, almost
unconscious and intoxicated Karna failed to
counter this fierce group attack.

---

Point-5: Karna was not using his celestial Vijaya
bow and his celestial chariot during this war. He
was using an ordinary bow and an ordinary
chariot at that time. Some Gandharvas cut off
Karna's bow, some slew his horses, some slew
his charioteer, some cut down his standard,
some cut down his umbrella, some cut down his
flagstaff, some cut off the yoke of his chariot,
some cut off the shaft of his chariot, some cut
off the wooden fender around it, and some cut
off the joints of it. This was the most ferocious
and brutal group attack in the whole
Mahabharata.

The original answer was posted at http://www.quora.com/Why-did-Karna-fled-from-battle-with-Chitrasena-Gandharvas

Comment: Can you please add sources from which edition of Mahabharata you took these? Quora doesn't count as a reference :D

Answer (score 0):

Chitrasen war was an unfair war. If the unfair part is not written in any scriptures, there is something called common sense. Arjun was Indra's son.

Sammohana weapon was given to Arjun by Indra. He used it in Virata war. We can't declare Arjun win the war because Bhishma was conscious but he preferred not to fight his beloved Arjun. Though we can declare Karna lost this one.

The Kurukshetra war was unfair to Pandavas as they had fewer soldiers. But as fact goes, Bhima never defeated Karna in Kurukshetra. In fact, it was otherwise. If you read deeply, Karna defeated each of the 5 Pandavas once during the war. Arjun defeated only Karna once and which had resulted in his death. And we all know what worked in Arjun's favor in this war and against Karna. 7 of them are mentioned below.

1. Krishna as charioteer and guide
2. Hanuman's presence in his chariot
3. Durga presence in his chariot
4. Karna's promise to Kunti of not killing other sons, except Arjun
5. Indra's disguised and took his Kavach and Kundal
6. Curse on Karna of chariot getting stuck and resulting to his death
7. Curse on Karna by Parshuram of forgetting the knowledge of using celestial weapons

All in all, Karan and Arjun never had a fair fight to decide who was a better at archery. And all the war Karna lost, there is one thing is common Indra.

Comment: A war is a war. Did Karna think that he was going to play in the war? He underestimated Gandharvas.Who told Karna not to get a better charioteer? Not to use divine weapons? Was he not aware that he was fighting Arjuna? What happened when he used the Vijaya bow? There was no curse on Karna for forgetting divyastras. He defeated all pandavas? **Did you answer by watching a movie?** Did Hanuman fight on behalf of Arjun? No. Karna couldn't withstand Partha and he chose to fight against innocent soldiers rather than Arjuna.1/2

Comment: Arjuna earned every astra by hard penance. Why didn't Karna use his bow from his first day? He underestimated his opposition.Arjuna defeated Karna even with Kavacha and kundala in Virata war. When Kauravas suspected that there would be Arjuna in Virata, did Karna and others think that Arjuna would let them win? You are surely answering by watching Mahabharat serial. Arjuna defeated all the warriors in Virata war. **Bhishma and Drona too.**  Bhima defeated Karna. He flee from the battle field. When you are going to a war, you should be ready for anything. Karna didn't do that. 2/2

Comment: This is a plagiarized answer @Sarvabhouma please collapse it immediately or delete it.

Comment: @Knowledge If it's a plagiarized answer, You can mention the original link and flag for moderator intervention. They will look at it.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma i meant for Maroof's answer, here is the link to the original link: https://www.facebook.com/karnavsarjun.official/posts/an-analysis-of-the-gandharva-war_____this-thread-is-so-long-but-i-request-alltru/875769469177930/ And maroofs answer can be found in this question thread.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because karna was a incompetent warrior. He was not brave or righteous either. Karna chose to run away when his friend Duryodhana and his wives were at the mercy of the Gandharva infantry of Chitrasena's army.

Alot of Karna fans talk about common sense, yet they never apply that to karna's defeats and character. They first claim this Gandharva war was unfair then they claim that its not mentioned in any scriptures. First of all the truth is that all authentic versions of Mahabharata include this incident.

Second of all this war was not unfair, karna was not drunk, and since karna countered the illusions of Ghatotkatcha he has no excuse for failing against Chitrasena's illusions.

Here is a screenshot from BORI Critical Edition of Arjuna's battle with the Gandharvas.[image]As we can see Arjuna performs far better than karna, in a short amount of time Arjuna killed 1 million Gandharvas.

Compare this to Karna who could not even kill a fraction of that amount. As we read in Vana Parva, only a thousand Gandharvas is all that it took to defeat karna.[image]

Karna lost to a thousand Gandharvas, but a Million Gandharvas lost to Arjuna.
Rank of warriors should be like this.

1. Arjuna
2. a million Gandharvas
3. a thousand gandharvas
4. karna

Before anyone asks for the source of screenshots they all come from Bori Mahabharat, these verses are present in KMG Mahabharata as well.